# merge object array in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

i have tow arrays, so i want assign the values from array to array of objects, if have same id
this is my code, but the foreach repeat the first array,

```
let cars =[
  {
    sap_code:"audi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"a4"},
      {id:55,name:"a5"},
      
    ]
  },
  {
    sap_code:"chevi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"x4"},
      {id:55,name:"x5"},
       
    ]
  }
]

let cars2= [{id:55, value:25000}]
let joinCar = []
cars.forEach((value)=> {
  value.products.forEach((value2)=>{  
    const existing = cars2.filter((v, i)=> {
      return (v.id == value2.id);
    });
    if (existing.length) {
      value2.value = existing[0].value;
      joinCar.push(value)
    } else {
      value2.value = null;
      joinCar.push(value);
    }
  });
})
```

and i want expected
something like this

```
[
      {
        sap_code:"audi",
        products:[
          {id:23,name:"a4"},
          {id:55,name:"a5", value:25000},
          
        ]
      },
      {
        sap_code:"chevi",
        products:[
          {id:23,name:"x4"},
          {id:55,name:"x5", value:25000},
          {id:29,name:"x6"},
        ]
      }
]
```

Comment: Show the expected output.

Comment: where's the id 29 come from?

Comment: How it knows it must attach to ```chevi``` not others?

Answer (score 1):

Do the `push` in the outer `forEach`, not the inner one.

```js
let cars =[
  {
    sap_code:"audi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"a4"},
      {id:55,name:"a5"},
      
    ]
  },
  {
    sap_code:"chevi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"x4"},
      {id:55,name:"x5"},
       
    ]
  }
]

let cars2= [{id:55, value:25000}]
let joinCar = []
cars.forEach((value)=> {
  value.products.forEach((value2)=>{  
    const existing = cars2.filter((v, i)=> {
      return (v.id == value2.id);
    });
    if (existing.length) {
      value2.value = existing[0].value;
    } else {
      value2.value = null;
    }
  });
  joinCar.push(value);
})

console.log(joinCar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let cars =[
  {
    sap_code:"audi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"a4"},
      {id:55,name:"a5"},
      
    ]
  },
  {
    sap_code:"chevi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"x4"},
      {id:55,name:"x5"},
       
    ]
  }
]

let cars2 = [{id:55, value:25000}]
const joinCar = [...cars]  // you originally created a new array
for(const {products} of joinCar)
  for(const product of products) {
    const car2 = cars2.find(({id})=>id===product.id)
    if(car2) product.value = car2.value
  }

console.log(joinCar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a `hashtable` and `reduce`, the complexity can be significantly reduced. So the best approach would be to create a hashtable with the id and values of `cars2` so as to find the match and use `reduce` over `cars` something like this:
.

```js
let cars =[
  {
    sap_code:"audi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"a4"},
      {id:55,name:"a5"},
      
    ]
  },
  {
    sap_code:"chevi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"x4"},
      {id:55,name:"x5"},
       
    ]
  }
]

let cars2= [{id:55, value:25000}];
var hasTable = {};

for(let i of cars2){
 hasTable[i.id] = i.value //create a hashtable with id and values
}

cars.reduce((a,v)=>{
  let val =  v.products.find(k=> hasTable[k.id]);

  if(val){
    val.value = hasTable[val.id];
  }
  return a
})

console.log(cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cars =[
  {
    sap_code:"audi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"a4"},
      {id:55,name:"a5",value:4500},
      
    ]
  },
  {
    sap_code:"chevi",
    products:[
      {id:23,name:"x4"},
      {id:55,name:"x5"},
       
    ]
  }
];

let cars2 = [{id:55, value:25000}];
cars.forEach(car=>{
  cars2.forEach(newCar=>{
    let fc = car.products.findIndex(c=>c.id===newCar.id);
    if (fc !==-1) car.products[fc].value=newCar.value;
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(cars))
```